# package.json reference value from external json

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app, sentry

I have a metadata.json file which includes some values:

```
{"build":{"major":0,"minor":88}}
```

In my create-react-app project, I need to run the script to upload sentry map files:

```
"sentry" : "sentry-cli releases files 0.88 upload-sourcemaps --validate ./build"
```

where the 0.88 should be pulled from the metadata.json file. I can then run it with:

```
npm run sentry
```

How can I pull the value 0.88 from the metadata.json file with build major/ minor and insert it into the sentry command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a solution to do this in `package.json` itself.

This is how I would have solved this problem:

1. Create a new `js` file. Let's say the name is `run-command.js`.
2. Add a line `node ./run-command.js` inside the `script` object in `package.json`.
3. Import the `metadata.json` file in this newly created file and extract the necessary data
4. Execute your command

**Example:**

*package.json*

```
scripts: {
  "sentry": "node ./run-command.js"
}
```

*run-command.js*

```
const metadata = require('./metadata.json');
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec(`echo ${metadata.build.major}`, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
  if (err) {
    // node couldn't execute the command
    return;
  }

  // the *entire* stdout and stderr (buffered)
  console.log(`stdout: ${stdout}`);
  console.log(`stderr: ${stderr}`);
});
```

Replace echo with your command. It would look something like `./node_modules/.bin/sentry ...`

You can use a bash script like `./sentry.sh` if you are comfortable with shell scripts.